# Filename with uppercase letter mistaken for a lowercase letter in C program

Tags: c, bash, command-line, io, filenames

I want to write files with a naming convention involving underscores, lowercase and uppercase letters, like the small working example here:

```
// test.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    /* code */

    char myfile[14]="test_letter_i\0";
    FILE *fptr;

    fptr=fopen(myfile, "w");
    fprintf(fptr, "This is a test\n");
    fclose(fptr);

    char myfile2[14]="test_letter_I\0";

    fptr=fopen(myfile2, "w");
    fprintf(fptr, "This is a test\n");
    fclose(fptr);

    return 0;
}
```

However, when looking at the files written, there is only one (test_letter_i) in the folder. I couldn't find an answer to this question. I don't know if it comes from C or the terminal emulator I'm using. I'm on Macbook (x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0, Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)) and using iTerm with zsh.

Comment: The filesystem is probably set to be case-insensitive. I think that is the default for Mac OSX.

Comment: I've gotten the same result after testing on macOS. - it appears both calls are accessing the same file. This must be a macOS feature indeed

Comment: Was the file contents of the first or 2nd?  (Use different lines of text).

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you, looks like that's the problem... Any idea on how to change that?

Comment: Thank you @wquinoa as well (couldn't tag more than one...)

Comment: @Ek55 I wouldn't recommend turning on the case sensitivity of the `/` partition in macOS, as many software rely on it being case-insensitive; even Apple programs will most probably break because of it. Change you naming convention, it's safer.

Comment: Although that ship sailed long ago, this confusion is one good reason to never allow case-insensitive file systems.  I don't know what problem the case insensitivity solves, but it certainly creates problems.